# Natural statements of high logical complexity in algebraic theories

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Is there a natural "algebraic" first order theory $T$ and a formula $\varphi$ such that $\varphi$ has high quantifier complexity over $T$?

By "algebraic" I mean not explicitly arithmetic or set theoretic; examples I have in mind are theories of graph/group/ring. By natural I mean $\varphi$ should be a property that originates in non-logical context (so it should not be obtained by, e.g. coding arithmetic). By high I mean $\varphi$ should be at least $\Sigma_3$ or $\Pi_3$; I have the feeling that many properties about groups are either $\forall\exists$ or not expressible in first order logic at all.

Admittedly these requirements are quite vague; basically I want to exclude theories like $\mathsf{PA}$ or $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Also note that my question is different from [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281894/examples-of-statements-with-a-high-quantifier-complexity).

Comment: In what sense in the theory of graphs "algebraic"?

Comment: Here is a nice recent example from MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/440235/2126

Comment: @AlexKruckman $B'_G$ and $D_G$ seem like $\Pi_1$ to me so the conditions in the proposition seem like $\Sigma_2$. If I'm wrong could you briefly explain why?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you need an additional block of existential quantifiers to express that G is the semidirect product of the two subgroups.